# Выполнить python из php (windows)

Tags: php, python, windows

Использую Open Server на Windows чтобы поднять локалку. Использую вот такой код для теста:

```
$python = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
$cmd = "$python -V";
echo $cmd;
echo system($cmd);
echo exec($cmd);
echo shell_exec($cmd);
echo passthru($cmd);
```

В итоге ни один из вариантов ничего не выводят. Хотя если выполнить из cmd "C:\Python27\python.exe -V", то все работает. В чем может быть проблема

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему добавлением команды "start":

```
$cmd = "start $python -V";
```

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, все **опасные функции отключены в PHP**, чтобы предотвратить выполнение вредоносного кода и защитить сервер от несанкционированного внедрения за счет ошибок программиста, которые не всегда корректно используют данные функции.

Удалите из php.ini (конфигурация php) строку disable_functions, где перечислены все функции которые Вы используете, и данные команды будут выполняться.